# reading password protected excel file using matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read a password protected excel file, the problem I am having with the following code is it does not take care of password, but instead excel application opens but user has to go to taskbar and click excel app to see the password query.

```
path = fullfile(pwd,'tests.xls')

e=actxserver('excel.application');
eW = e.Workbooks;
eF = eW.Open(file3,'GSL');


[num,txt,raw]  = xlsread(file3, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two ways to solve the problem. I don't have access to a Windows machine so you'll have to figure out the details yourself:

1. Use Matlab's GUI functions to ask the user for the password. Then, supply that password to the `Open` method along with the filename ([Excel Open method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open%28v=office.11%29.aspx#Y310)).
2. After calling `actxserver` try to bring the Excel window into focus so that when you open the file, the password dialog box is visible. Something like described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-33DJ6K/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-33DJ6K) should work.

Comment: Error using Interface.Microsoft_Excel_12.0_Object_Library.Workbooks/Open
Invoke Error, Dispatch Exception:
Source: Microsoft Office Excel
Description: Open method of Workbooks class failed
Help File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM
Help Context ID: 0

Error in Search_Tool>open_file_Callback (line 866)
eF = eW.Open('H:\tests.xls','GSL');

Comment: I am doing what I am asking in the question above getting that top error.

Comment: What is the 'GSL' part of the argument? Can't see that in the docs.